# C++ Rnd() Fault

Tags: c++, random, fault

Guys I'm getting this really weird fault with my program when I run it. This is the important code:

**variables (edit):**

```
const short int maxX = 100;
const short int maxZ = 100;
const short int lakeChance = 0.9;
```

**addLake function (edit):**

```
void addLake(Sect sector[][maxZ], int x, int z){    
    sector[x][z].setMaterial(1);
}
```

**main source (edit):**

```
//Generating land mass
for (int x = 0; x < maxX; x++){
    for (int z = 0; z < maxZ; z++){
        //Default material
        sector[x][z].setMaterial(0);

        //Add lake/sea source
        int r = rand();
        float r1 = (r % 1000);
        float r2 = r1 / 1000;

        if (r2 <= lakeChance) addLake(sector, x, z);
    }
}
```

The fault is, that whatever I change the 'lakeChance' value to, the result seems to be exactly the same. As in the addLake function seems to be called about 3 to 6 times every launch despite me changing the value of lakeChance higher (i.e.: 0.5, 0.7, 0.9). The function is only called all the time when I change the value of 'lakeChance' to 1. The random number generator works fine btw so the result are somewhat varying every time.

Comment: This is a brilliant time to produce a [Short, Selfcontained, compilable, correct, example](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: I know I'm going to regret asking this, but where is the variable you're passing in for `sector` declared/allocated?

Comment: How often do you run the main source during the execution of your program? I.e., out of how many tries is the figure "3 to 6 times"?

Comment: Have you tried printing the values for `random` to see if there might be an RNG problem?

Comment: I'm not sure if you are talking about the distribution of the random numbers but C++11 has some mechanisms to make it more uniform:http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/normal_distribution

Comment: Please write and post a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) which predictably reproduces your problem. This will help you in understanding what is happening as well as increase your ability to explain it to us so that we can help you.

Comment: Did you ever call `seed` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see nothing *obviously* wrong per se. So I tried the following bit of code:

```
int test(float chance)
{
    int call = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i != 100000; i++)
    {
        int r = rand();

        float r1 = (r % 1000);

        float r2 = r1 / 1000;

        if(r2 <= chance)
            call++;
    }

    cout << "Chance is " << chance << ": " << call << " invocations or "
         << ((100.0 * call) / 100000.0) << "% of the time!" << endl;

    return call;    
}
```

Predictably, I got these results:

```
Chance is 0.1: 10216 invocations or 10.216% of the time!
Chance is 0.2: 20232 invocations or 20.232% of the time!
Chance is 0.3: 30357 invocations or 30.357% of the time!
Chance is 0.4: 40226 invocations or 40.226% of the time!
Chance is 0.6: 60539 invocations or 60.539% of the time!
Chance is 0.7: 70539 invocations or 70.539% of the time!
Chance is 0.8: 80522 invocations or 80.522% of the time!
Chance is 0.9: 90336 invocations or 90.336% of the time!
Chance is 1: 100000 invocations or 100% of the time!
```

How many lakes are you trying to add?

Comment: +1 I get similar results using an entirely different code base.

Comment: I did that in my function already look, but whatever I change the value of chance or lakeChance to the result doesn't change at all. I always get the function called 1 to 10 times whatever the chance.

Comment: I still don't quite understand the problem that you are having. Is your problem that you get too many lakes? Too few? Can you tell us what you are *expecting* to have happen and what *actually* happens?

Comment: Don't worry I fixed it, it turns out to be that I forgot to change the variable lakeChance to a float instead of an int, lol.

Answer (score -1):

try to `randomize()` before calling `rand()`.

Comment: I did, its not to do with the random numbers, they come up different every time.